# Android remove variable content on concat or merge variables

Tags: java, android

in this below code as :

```
String marketUUid = "bc76b7a5-3166-11e6-b8fe-ec9a74f8851a";

String filePath = imagePath + "/" + marketUUid + "/" + "banners";
File   checkMarketBannerFolder = new File(filePath);
```

when i try to merge or `concat` marketUUid with other variables such as `imagePath` and put it to `filePath`, its removed from this operation and i dont have that variable, it means after merge variables my `filePath` have:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Signal/image/banners
```

but this code doesn't have any problem:

```
String filePath = imagePath + "/" + "bc76b7a5-3166-11e6-b8fe-ec9a74f8851a" + "/" + "banners";
```

whats happen ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a by far more clean and readable way to format your strings:

```
String marketUUid = "bc76b7a5-3166-11e6-b8fe-ec9a74f8851a";
String imagePath = "image";

String filePath = String.format(
        "%s/%s/banners",
        imagePath,
        marketUUid
);
```

Comment: `filePath` content is `/storage/emulated/0/Signal/image//banners` now,removed again

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy The value of filePath after execution of my code is `image/bc76b7a5-3166-11e6-b8fe-ec9a74f8851a/banners`. I really do not see what's the issue, sir

Comment: what's your android version?

Comment: my problem is lenght of string variables. i have to substring value of variable